# Correct way to use <uses- library> to create module that depend on an external JAR library

Tags: android, android-library

In this page: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#Considerations

It states that:

> You can develop a library module that depends on an external library. (for example, the Maps external library). In this case, the dependent app must build against a target that includes the external library (for example, the Google APIs Add-On). Note also that both the library module and the dependent app must declare the external library in their manifest files, in a  element.

---

So I tried to do what the paragraph says above.

1- I created a module that has this in its `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.0.0'
```

2- and I added this in my `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-library
android:name="com.twitter.sdk"
android:required="true"/>
```

3- I imported my `.aar` file to my main app.

4- I added the same code into my **main app** `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-library
android:name="com.twitter.sdk"
android:required="true"/>
```

But of-course it shows an error:

[image]

Comment: check if you have app installed on your device with same package name if yes uninstall it first. Mostly happens due to having play store app installed in device and we try to install app through Android studio.

Comment: @NileshDeokar, I created a new project with new unique name but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `<uses-library>` from your manifest. It it *only* for cases where you are trying to use a "library" that is part of a device's firmware. The "Maps" example that they cite is from the long-obsolete Google Maps V1 for Android implementation.

I am not aware of any device manufacturer that has advised its developers to add `<uses-library>` elements to their manifest for `com.twitter.sdk`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. when I delete it and then my main app calls a class that launches twitter sdk. It will crash with an error that says: `can't find path for class twitter sdk.confi`.

Comment: What is the correct approach if I want to create a module that has twitter sdk or any other libraries found in my modules `gradle` ?

Comment: @Suhaib: Either add the `compile` lines for the Twitter libraries to both the library module and the app module, or have the app module pull in the library module directly (not via importing some AAR), or publish the AAR as an artifact in a repository and have the app depend upon the AAR from that repository. An AAR on its own has no details regarding its transitive dependencies, just as a JAR on its own has no details regarding its transitive dependencies.

Comment: thank you,  regarding this sentence, `AAR as an artifact in a repository`. Sorry but i'm new. Do you mean upload it to maven/jCenter ?

Comment: @Suhaib: It could be a local repository. However, unless you have 2+ apps that are going to use this library *soon* (i.e., immediately, or in days or weeks), I would recommend simply having the library be a module in the same project as the app, and use `compile project(':libraryname)`) to have the app refer to the library. That is simpler that fussing with a local Maven repository when there is only one app consuming the library.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have the library module and I am using it by "implementation project(':xyz') in my app module.
and my "xyz" module is dependant on 3rd party library.
Do I need to implement those 3rd party libraries to my main app module as well?

Comment: @KalpeshWadekar: "Do I need to implement those 3rd party libraries to my main app module as well?" -- that will depend on how the third-party library is added to `xyz`. If you used `implementation`, then yes, consumers of `xyz` would need to manually add the third-party library. If you used `api`, then Gradle will handle this automatically. If you have additional concerns in this area, I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can provide a [mcve] showing the Gradle files fro `xyz` and a module that depends upon `xyz`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Yes I have used `implementation` of 3rd party library to `xyz` module and yes I have to `implement` those dependencies in my main `app` module. But I didn't get the reason, why we need to duplicate the dependencies?

Comment: @KalpeshWadekar: `implementation` says "nothing else needs this". That is rarely the case for a dependency in a library module. `api` says "anything that depends on me also needs this". This is the normal case for a library module. See [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations). The Android Gradle plugin is modeled after the Java library plugin, so you can read more about this in [the Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) as well.